# Adding Multi-Column Picker Functionality to a HTML Select Control

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

I have a simple  HTML element on my webpage which shows a UIPickerView control on iPhone and mobile devices. Now, I want to replace that with 4 column picker view control. Something like this: Each column is a select item which is scrollable and user can select different combinations.

[image]

How can I do that? Is that even possible?

Comment: put a space between them? `<option>12 4 5 3</option>`

Comment: Each of the items/columns are scrollable. Just like when you view the select html item in a mobile device.